React component for agSetColumnFilter
I'd like to wrap the standard ag-grid set filter component, so that it works in reverse (it stores the unchecked elements in the model, not the checked ones).
Is it possible to get the react component that corresponds to the name 'agSetColumnFilter', and render it in a custom filter component? I would like to not replicate the rendering of checkboxes.
Thank you!
